# Understanding of a difficult sentence

Tags: ellipsis

> A grammar, we have said, is divided into 2 major components, syntax and morphology. This division follows from the special status of the word as a basic linguistic unit, with syntax dealing with the combination of words to make sentences, and morphology with the form of words themselves.

Questions

1. Is the word "dealing" omitted？
2. Are all the bracketed words within the "with" construction?

A grammar, we have said, is divided into 2 major components, syntax and methodology. This division follows from the special status of the word as a basic linguistic unit, with syntax dealing **with** [ the combination of words to make sentences, and morphology **dealing** with the form of words themselves.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *... with syntax dealing with* [*the combination of words to make sentences*], [*and morphology ___ with the form of words*].

The second "dealing" is not essential. This is called 'gapped coordination' (or 'gapping'), which allows the verb to be omitted in the second coordinate if it is recoverable from the first coordinate.

The gap marked '___' is understood by reference to the first coordinate: in this case "dealing".

Yes, the whole coordination is complement of the preposition "with".

Answer (score 2):

It's "...with syntax dealing with [ the combination of words to make sentences ], and morphology (dealing) with [ the forms of words themselves ]."

The second "dealing" is indeed 'ommitted'.  Perhaps better to say elided - it's not 'missing', in the sense of a mistake; it is implied by the sentence structure.